# How to use Printf

Tags: java, input, printf, output, println

How can I use printf to print a line with multiple floating point numbers that need to be rounded. I know I need to use "%6.2f" to round it to two decimal points. I need to have the variable "temp" and "v" rounded to two decimal points.

I have tried this:

System.out.printf("%6.2f," temp + " " + " degrees Fahrenheit is" + "%6.2f," v + " " + "Celsius");

this did not work.

System.out.printf(temp + " " + " degrees Fahrenheit is" + " " + v + " " + "Celsius");

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for:

```
System.out.printf("%6.2f degrees Fahrenheit is %6.2f Celsius", temp, v);
```